# Restrict MKAnnotationView to drag only over/with already drawn polyline

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have an `array` of `coordinates` and draw a `polyline` using these. At center of `polyline` I m showing an `annotation` using `MKAnnotationView`. This is `dragable`, I want it to be dragged only with adjesent to or over the `polyline`. Do not allow user to move and drag away from `polyline`?

How this could be done any ideas ?

I only found this delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
}
```

but it is calling after position change and its `view.annotaion.coordinates` are read only. I can not reset them...

Please let me know if this is possible using MKMapView? Any possible way to achieve?